# OneDrive and OneDrive Business OAuth with javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, oauth-2.0, onedrive

I'm integrating OneDrive and OneDrive Enterprise API into a current project. I'm stucked at the OAuth process, specifically generating the refresh token and access token for later use.

These calls are made via an AJAX Request, and apparently Microsoft OAuth endpoints does not support CORS (Missing Access-Control-Allow-Origin Header in the response).

Request Headers with AJAX:

```
POST /common/oauth2/token HTTP/1.1
Host: login.microsoftonline.com
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 987
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Accept: */*
Origin: http://localhost
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Referer: http://localhost
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
```

Response Headers:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Expires: -1
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
x-ms-request-id: 4af29899-6eec-485b-81f4-eb654e4ce8f0
client-request-id: e307d3b2-dcdd-4e6f-b892-3f0ab9b6d8e7
x-ms-responsehealth: TargetId=ESTSFE_IN_166;Action=None;Category=None;Health=0;Load=25;
P3P: CP="DSP CUR OTPi IND OTRi ONL FIN"
Set-Cookie: esctx=AAABAAAA0TWEUN3YUUq5vuCvmnaQicX4MVI1_yI1ufS9w-9YAaQPxCGXvR8oiEo7fqzcDM0AYPgVgmjFUN03Xw6nUdD_D5MkLLyoACMzmimrn53jr-RxNb2RhKeckZwC4HrTWqxbR7Wjf9jm75f4zPfOohV_hCns_42xQ8byFsQqtqsd7XVIG6tBzxrJAm8Kyb1bQRgnIAA; domain=.login.microsoftonline.com; path=/; secure; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: x-ms-gateway-slice=productionb; path=/; secure; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: stsservicecookie=ests; path=/; secure; HttpOnly
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Thu, 21 Jul 2016 18:29:16 GMT
Content-Length: 3024
```

Console error:

XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/token. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Has anyone come up with the same issue?

Do I need to setup something on Microsoft Azure console?

Comment: This is by design, single page apps are not allowed to request refresh tokens, but instead require SPAs to use implicit flow. If you need to continue to maintain access after the 1 hour expiration of the access-token you are given, there is a way to silently get a new token as long as the user is still signed in. The method for doing this is documented here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-v2-protocols-implicit/#refreshing-tokens

Comment: Thanks Ryan. I guess I would have to create a bypass proxy to support this.

Comment: You shouldn't need to do that, although that is an option. You can use a hidden IFRAME to silently repeat the token code flow, which as long as the user is still logged in in their browser, will give you a new access token. It's only if you expect to cache the user's login for a long duration of time that you'd need a refresh token.

Comment: Sorry,I can not understand your solution. I am having the  same issue just trying to get the access token for first time. My ajax request falls into an error because of Access-Control-Allow-Origin but i still can see the 200 response on fiddler. what is the solution here?